# Why does sympy.solve not output anything?

Tags: python, sympy, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to solve a system of equations. The equations in the example below are the first derivatives of a Lagrangian function (LDash 1 through 7), which I obtained by pen and paper. The solutions to the system should give the candidates for maxima and minima.

The choice variables are `X1, X2, LC, LA, s, u`, while all other symbols are place holders for positive reals.

The script runs but then doesn't display anything in my console. In the examples throughout the [SymPy documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html) `solve` outputs the solution. Can you help me find out why it does not do that in my example below?

I am completely new to Python, so please let me know how I can improve. Thanks!

```
# import stuff
from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex=True)
from sympy import Function
from sympy.solvers import solve
import sympy as sp

X1, X2, LC, LA, s, u = sp.var('X_1, X_2, L_C, L_A, s, u', positive=True);

# import exogenous variables

a1, a2, a3, a4, S1, S2, S3, S4, p1, p2, p3, p4, fdash, vdash,f, v = sp.symbols('alpha_1, alpha_2, alpha_3, alpha_4, S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4, p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, \hat{F}, \hat{V}, f, v', positive=True)

v0 = sp.symbols('v_0') # raw skill level
i = sp.symbols('\hat{\imath}') # children in the household - time endowment
I = sp.symbols('I') # household size and total time endowment
climate = sp.symbols('theta') # climate variable
capital = sp.symbols('K') # quasi fixed land and (non-human) capital
lam = sp.symbols('\lambda') # shadow prices (lagrange multiplier)

# pen-and-paper: derivatives of the Lagrange function w.r.t choice variables

LDash1 = a1/(X1-S1)-lam*p1 # L' w.r.t X1
LDash2 = a2/(X2-S2)-lam*p2 # L' w.r.t X2
LDash3 = -a3/(I-i-LA-S3) + 2*lam*p3 + lam*p1*fdash # L' w.r.t LA
LDash4 = -1/(i-LC) - a4/(i-LC-S4) + 2*lam*p4 + lam*p1*fdash*(-s*u + s*v +(1-s)*v0) # L' w.r.t LC
LDash5 = lam*p1*fdash *(-u*LC + v*LC - v0*LC) # L' w.r.t. s
LDash6 = lam*p1*fdash *(-s*LC + s*vdash*LC) # L' w.r.t u
LDash7 = p1*X1 + p2*X2 -2*p3*I + 2*p3*i + 2*p3*LA -2*p4*i + 2*p4*LC + p1*f # L' w.r.t lambda

solve((LDash1,LDash2, LDash3, LDash4, LDash5, LDash6, LDash7), (X1,X2,LA,LC,u,s))
```

Comment: Why would it display anything? You didn't `print` anything, and `sympy.solvers.solve` presumably doesn't output anything either, so you end up with no output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems, firstly the solve call will take a very long time and potentially not return successfully at all. Secondly even if it would return, say you replace the call with `solve(LDash1, X1)` the return value of `solve` is never printed. Try to replace the last line with this for example to be able to debug your equations

```py
solve(LDash1, X1)
```

The reason the answer is printed in the documentation is because they use [*interactive mode*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode), this is normally indicated by the Python interactive prompt `>>>`

Comment: Hi @vidstige. I had already debugged it like you suggest, but even then it doesn't output anything at all. Funny enough, debugging the script didn't flag any errors either.

Comment: Oh yes! Interactive mode it is, indeed. I'm trying again assigning a name to the solution and printing it. cheers.

Comment: Now ```solve``` outputs an empty list...so I guess no solutions?

Comment: You are trying to solve 7 equations for 6 unknowns so there is a good chance that no solution exists. An empty list returned from `solve` usually means that it thinks there are no solutions although in the case of a system with many symbolic parameters it can mean that a solution does not exist for almost all possible values of the parameters. Did you mean to have a 7th variable listed as an unknown?

Comment: Hi Oscar. Indeed, I made a dumb mistake: I didn't include the lagrange multiplier lambda as a variable in solve. cheers